# Updating Powershell WPF component from runspacepool thread

Tags: wpf, multithreading, powershell, delegates, dispatcher

I've asked this question a couple times, haven't seemed to get this to work yet, but it looks like I'm getting closer. I'm looking to be able to run a process within runspacepool and update my RichTextBox with results such as exitcodes.. etc.

I cannot for the life of me seem to get any components dispatchers work for me, here's what I have.

```
     $TestScriptblock = {

     New-Item c:\TestRunPool -type directory

     $richTextBox1.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke([action]{
     $richTextBox1.AppendText("test")                   
     },"Normal")

     }





   $RunspacePool = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1,8)
   $RunspacePool.Open()
   $PSinstance = [powershell]::Create().AddScript($TestScriptblock)
   $PSinstance.RunspacePool = $RunspacePool
   $PSinstance.BeginInvoke()
```

I put `New-Item c:\TestRunPool -type directory` just to see if it runs the thread, and it does, I just cannot seem to touch the richtextbox from any thread other than the GUI thread.

Comment: What `$richTextBox1` suppose to mean if you just windup new `RunspacePool`? Did you inspect `$PSinstance.Streams.Error` after invocation?

Comment: It's a wpf GUI so $richtextbox is a rich text box lol